# Navigate between views of the same type with PRISM

Tags: wpf, prism

I want to use unlimited number of tabs with same view in Telerik Docking control, but I dont know how to navigate to exact tab. It always navigate me to the last opened tab.

Can someone point me in the right direction and say how to organize navigation in such case?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `INavigationAware` in the tabs' view models and return `true` from `IsNavigationTarget` from the tab you want to replace and false from all others.

Comment: How this will help me with navigation to the certain view?

Comment: The tab control region is normally one that accepts multiple views, so if one tab or its view model says it is no navigation target, a new view will be added instead of reusing the existing one.

Comment: Did you actually read my question? I asked "how to navigate to exact tab" So , I am asking again. I have 10 identical tabs. But I need to navigate to only one of them, not random, not first in list, but navigate to concrete tab, how I will achieve this?

Comment: Then the other way round - return true on from the view model of the tab you want to replace.